# UITextField, set placeholder after text in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I need to keep the placeholder after the text, when click on the text box i need to clear only the placeholder and able to type characters.
[image]

In this Marissa is the name text and (First Name) is placeholder. Once i start editing placeholder need to clear and start editing complete text.

How can i achieve that?

Comment: you should use label to show placeholder and when user click then hide the placeholder and check if text is not nil then do accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer below code.

**Just copy-paste below code in `viewdidload()`**

```
textfield.attributedPlaceholder = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Yourtext%@",Placehodertext] attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: color}];
```

**Assign Delegate of `UITextfield` to `self`.**

```
textfield.delegate =  self


-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
   textfield.text = @"Yourtext"
   return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have found some similar custom textfield in the below URL. If you find this suitable, you can use it.

[image]

[TUTORIAL / SOURCE](http://www.code4app.net/ios/Text-entry-controls-which-contain-a-built-in-title_label-so-that-you-don%E2%80%98t-have/54bcdb69e24741296f8b4567)

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1:**
Make the text filed attributed form `xib` and set the "Marisa (First Name)"
and change the color for the (First Name) as grey color .

**Step 2:**
And in the Textfiled `DidBiginEditing` method change the `textField.text` to "Marisa".

Answer (score 1):

You can not set place holder along with the text in a textfield.
But there is one alternate for this.
Textfields has something called left view which you can make readOnly view.
Try this :

```
UIView *paddingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];
UILabel *textLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:paddingView.bounds];
textLabel.text = @"Marissa";
[paddingView addSubView:textLabel]; 
                textField.leftView = paddingView;
                textField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be achieved in several ways:

1. Use the `attributedText` property of `UITextField` instance to apply a styling for different parts of the text. Here you need to properly define the property each time a user has changed the input by using [delegate methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITextFieldDelegate) or  by observing `UIControl` [Control Events](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Control_Events).
2. If the structure of the text input is fixed and predefined you could use a batch of fields to imitate a more complex/smart field. Here, for example, you need to put two fields beside. One for the last name, second for the first name. Or you can use a combination of `UILabel` and `UITextField` if one the part is not editable. Such an approach allows you to configure a separate part of a complex field as you want: different placeholders, fonts, keyboard styles, etc.